# AssertionError: Request global variable is not set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I know this is a duplicate question but by referring previous answers i couldn't find the solution yet.

I am using Google report api to fetch logs. 
Please refer this link:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/libraries

Everything goes well and I am able to generate authorize URL using scope,client id etc.
But I am not able to redirect user to URL to fetch "code" from authorize URL.

I tried using webapp2 script but throws error = **AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.**

Here is the code I am using for redirection:

```
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        path='my authorize url path'
        return self.redirect(path) #throws error on this line


a1=MainPage() #object to call class

a2=a1.get() #call method of class
```

Where i am going wrong ? If webapp2 having standard bug for self.redirect, then which other framework can help to to perform same operation?

If i use `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])` instead of creating objects then it doesnt even call `get(self)` function.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to call the get handler like that, and you can't just instantiate the handler like that, it needs to be initialised with a request.  Have a look at the class definition of webapp2.RequestHandler

Comment: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
I tried this too. But as i mentioned in my post it doesnt call 

get(self) method.
What exactly i need to do properly call webapp2 script.
I doesnt know webaap2 programming.
I am forced to use webapp2 to execute google api reports.

ANy syntax or example would really help if you can provide.

Comment: The get method will be called when you access the URL mapped to the handler.  WHat does your app.yaml look like ?

Comment: How do I insert ipdb line it gives me error no module named ipdb. I already did pip install ipdb